# Do blocking input ports increases security?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, port, central-processing-unit

1-Do blocking unused input ports in firewall increases system security? 
How? (as there is no daemon listening on those ports anyway)

2-Do dropping those unused ports will positively or negatively affect CPU load?(compared to accepting them)

Answer (score 2):

I would say :

1) This is, IMHO, a false positive question : unused ports should be blocked by default.
Only used ports should be opened.

2) Dropping or Accepting is not what will affect firewall CPU performance : it is more the total rules it has to parse, from the filter table, before taking a decision : place most used access rules at the beginning of your filter table.

Comment: thanks  , 1:this is exactly my question! why we should block unused ports by default? how it will benefit us?

Comment: Your benefit will be to protect you against holes from services you may have running on a server but that you don't want to serve to the client. e.g : on Windows RPC is open. What if you want to just open IIS on port 80 ? Just open HTTP/80 and don't let a backdoor open to hackers publishing RPC !

Comment: Can you tell me an example for *nix systems?
Thanks

Comment: A default-deny is the safest stance. That way, you must explicitly allow traffic that you want to accept.

Comment: Also the default-deny provides future security, any change to the listening ports must be allowed by the firewall before access is allowed from external sources.

Comment: On Linux ? I don't know, this will depend on services installed on your system. Run `netstat -anp` and compare what is actually open against what you really want to open.
`Do blocking input ports increases security?` Yes, this is what any serious Firewall do by default : close everything except what you have explicitely open.